# Is equivalent resistance always lower if we add a resistor to a passive electronic circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

How to prove that equivalent resistance of any passive network is always lower if we add a resistor between arbitrary two nodes?

Note that this is not necessarily a parallel circuit, 2 nodes that we connect with a resistor are not the same 2 nodes between we want to measure equivalent resistance but completely arbitrary 2 nodes in passive network.

So imagine a circuit with 4 access points: A, B, C and D. We want to measure equivalent resistance between A and B. How can you prove that Rab will be less if we add a resistor between C and D?

I tried to search the web but didn't have any success.

Comment: To clarify, I am interested in equivalent DC resistance in an arbitrary network made of resistors only. How can we prove that the resistance Rab is not higher if we connect nodes C and D with any resistor?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to prove this conjecture, you might instead look for counter-examples.  I think there are passive networks in which adding a resistor between C and D leaves the equivalent resistance between A and B unchanged.  A trivial counter-example is a network in which the only connections of node C are to D; there are others as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase, lower or equal.

Comment: @Serge: Well, you might try using the two-port open-circuit impedance matrix representation of the circuit, writing down the formula for the port-1 input resistance when port-2 is terminated by a resistor, and then use passivity and reciprocity to establish contraints on the various z-elements.

Comment: A balanced Wheatstone bridge is a nontrivial example.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  yes that's a good one.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to the equivalent two-port representation with 4 nodes A,B,C,D and 6 resistors, one resistor between each node. Note the resistor directly between A and B is not important to this question. So you have a diamond with your test ports A and B on top and bottom, and a cross-resistance between C and D.

Figure out the equivalent resistance of this 5-resistor network. 
I'll use the [extra element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem). It is:
$$R_{eq} = R^\infty_{in} \frac{R_{cd} + R^0_x}{R_{cd} + R^\infty_x}$$
where
$$R^\infty_{in} = (R_{ac} + R_{bc})\|(R_{ad} + R_{bd})$$
$$R^0_x = (R_{ac} \| R_{bc}) + (R_{ad} \| R_{bd})$$
$$R^\infty_x = (R_{ac} + R_{ad}) \| (R_{bc} + R_{bd})$$

$R_{cd}$ only appears in the first equation, and so $R_{eq}$ is an increasing function of $R_{cd}$ provided $R^0_x < R^\infty_x$. If $R^0_x = R^\infty_x$ then $R_{eq}$ is independant of $R_{cd}$. (That is also the most general counterexample to the original question.)

Prove algebraically that $R^0_x \le R^\infty_x$.

Even though you are only interested in DC resistance, it is true for general passive impedance.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but it got me thinking. And I did get an answer, so here it is...

We have a circuit, with $n$ nodes, numbered $0\ldots n-1$. There are also $b$ branches, numbered $0\ldots b-1$. Node number $0$ ($n_0$) is chosen to be the reference, or ground node. Node number $1$ ($n_1$) is kept $1 \mathrm{V}$ by a voltage source connected from $n_0$ to $n_1$. This is branch $0$ ($b_0$). The current on $b_0$ is defined to be flowing from $n_0$ to $n_1$, making $v_0$ (voltage of branch $0$) $-1\mathrm{V}$ by convention.

The equivalent resistance of the circuit as seen from nodes $n_1 - n_0$ is *defined* to be $1V / i_0$.

Now, in addition to $b_0$ consider another branch $b_1$, which is initially "not present", that is, initially $i_1 = 0$.

Here, we invoke Tellegen's theorem, which states the following:

Let $I_k$ be a set of branch currents on a circuit satisfying KCL.

Let $V_k$ be a set of branch voltages on a circuit satisfying KVL.

Then, for any such sets,

$\sum I_k\cdot V_k = 0$

Note that voltages and currents need *only* satisfy KCL and KVL, they need not be related to each other!

Now, going back to our setup, we have two sets of currents and voltages.

First, with $b_1$ not present.

$i_k$, $v_k$

$\sum i_k \cdot v_k = 0$

Expanding the special branches we have:

$v_0 i_0 + v_1 i_1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{b-1} v_k i_k = 0$

Since $v_0 = -1$ and $i_1 = 0$ we have:

$i_0 = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{b-1} v_k i_k$

When $b_1$ is inserted with a finite resistor, all currents and voltages are different. So we get:

$i'_0 = v'_1 i'_1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{b-1} v'_k i'_k$

Unfortunately, this takes us nowhere. But, there is a different approach: Use Tellegen's theorem, but with voltages and currents crossed between the two situations. This is perfectly valid:

$i_0 = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{b-1} v'_k i_k$

$i'_0 = v_1 i'_1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{b-1} v_k i'_k$

Up to here, everything is general. Now, we use the fact that, apart from $b_0$ which contains a voltage source, every element is a resistor:

$v_k = R_k \cdot i_k$

and

$v'_k = R_k \cdot i'_k$

Substituting theses for the voltages, the equations become:

$i_0 = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{b-1} R_k i'_k i_k$

$i'_0 = v_1 i'_1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{b-1} R_k i_k i'_k$

Note that the sums are exactly the same! Subtract the two equations to obtain:

$i'_0 - i_0 = v_1 i'_1$

Now, $v_1$ is the voltage where we are going to connect the new resistor before we have connected it. $i'_1$ is the current going through it after we have connected it. The product is definitely non-negative. This can be proven by considering the rest of the circuit as seen by the new resistor as a Thévénin equivalent circuit; the later current must be in the same direction as the initial voltage.

Since $R_{eq} = \frac{1V}{i_0}$ and $R'_{eq} = \frac{1V}{i_1}$, it follows that since $i'_0 > i_0$ then $R'_{eq} < R_{eq}$.

Well, we even know exactly by how much!

Comment: Very nice approach!  I think, though, that you overreach a bit when you state: "The product is definitely positive".  It is entirely possible that v1=0; consider the example of a balanced bridge mentioned by Emilio Pisanty in a comment above.

Comment: Yeah, it can be zero. We can still say it is nonnegative though. I will fix that.